# Referral Program at App Store Subscriptions

Tags: app-store, subscription

I want to develop a referral system for my subscribers. If someone suggests my app and his/her friend buy a subscription I want to give the referrer a one-month free subscription or extend the existing subscription to one month for free.
Is it possible to do this with offer codes?